# Syntax for combining elements and placeholders with jquery in function

Tags: jquery

I want to make a function out of this, so that I can pass a bunch of "people" through it.

```
$('#marc-leviste .portrait').one('inview', function (event, visible) {
  if (visible) {
    $("#marc-leviste .photo-list").responsiveSlides({
      auto: true
    });
  }
});
```

So I think I just need to go:

```
var my_function_name = function(my_element) {

  $('#marc-leviste .portrait').one('inview', function (event, visible) {
    if (visible) {
      $("#marc-leviste .photo-list").responsiveSlides({
        auto: true
      });
    }
  });

};
```

But then I can't remember how to deal with replacing the `#marc-leviste` with the `my_element' as far as syntax --- How do I mix them in the`$( --- )` ?

$('my_element .portrait') doesn't make sense...

assuming the final call would look like this..

my_function_name('#mark-leviste');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am not sure, i completely understand you question

```
my_function_name('#mark-leviste');
//then
$(myelement+' .portrait')
```

or if

```
my_function_name('mark-leviste');
//then
$('#'+myelement+' .portrait')
```

Comment: I think that's it! I still get tripped up with strings and mixing things because I don't have to do it too often. Thanks. I think there needs to be a space `' .portrait'` though in this case, right?